# Running PCA on a point cloud after ransac gives strange results

Tags: python, pca, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have the following dataset
http://www.mediafire.com/file/f8tz1zbpxvyvko7/Waltersdorf_F3.csv/file

The original dataset looks like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFDg.png)

I try to run ransac on it using pclpy to remove the outliers

After ransac
[image]

Then I apply PCA
and I get a totally strange different point cloud
[image]

Here is my code

```
def main():

    #process first point cloud
    f3data = np.loadtxt(r'c:\ahmed\Waltersdorf_F3.csv', delimiter=',',
                        dtype=[('id', np.str_, 20), ('x1', np.float32), ('x2', np.float32), ('x3', np.float32),
                               ])

    ptcloud_1 = np.vstack((f3data['x1'], f3data['x2'], f3data['x3'])).transpose()



    pc_1 = pcl.PointCloud.PointXYZ(ptcloud_1)
    X = np.vstack((pc_1.x, pc_1.y, pc_1.z)).transpose()

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d

    ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter3D(*X.T)
    plt.show()

    # pc_1 = pclpy.radius_outlier_removal(pc_1, search_radius=1.0, min_neighbors=4)
    #plotScatterRot3(f3rot)
    pc_type = utils.get_point_cloud_type(pc_1)
    seg = getattr(pcl.segmentation.SACSegmentation, pc_type)()
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(True)
    model = getattr(pcl.sample_consensus, "SACMODEL_" + 'PLANE'.upper())
    seg.setModelType(model)
    seg.setMethodType(pcl.sample_consensus.SAC_RANSAC)
    seg.setDistanceThreshold(1)
    seg.setInputCloud(pc_1)
    coefficients = pcl.ModelCoefficients()
    inliers = pcl.PointIndices()
    arr = np.ndarray(shape=(3,1), dtype= np.float32)
    arr[0] = 0
    arr[1] = 0
    arr[2] = 1
    seg.setAxis(arr)
    seg.segment(inliers, coefficients)

    inla = pc_1.xyz[inliers.indices]

    cloud_filtered = pcl.PointCloud.PointXYZ(inla)
    X = np.vstack((cloud_filtered.x, cloud_filtered.y, cloud_filtered.z)).transpose()

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # f = 0
    # for i in np.arange(-9.0,20, 1):

    # f = f + 1
    # plotInterploatedY(i, X, filename=r'c:\ahmed\absolute_%d.png'%f, plots='absolute')
    # plt.show()

    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d
    ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter3D(*X.T)
    plt.show()

    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)
    pca.fit(X)
    X = pca.transform(X)

    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d
    ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter3D(*X.T)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Running PCA distorts the point cloud as shown in the figure

Comment: I tried to save the point cloud AFTER pca and the result is like the original, but when PLOTTING it, I get very strange point cloud that's totally different

Comment: I still fail to see the actual question here. "Distorts" and "strange" have no meaning unless you specify what you expect should happen. Why do you think these results are strange? What should happen, and why? As far as I can tell, you just use the default PCA implementation from scikit-learn.

Comment: @OptimusCrime If you look at the original dataset, don't you see after running PCA on the point cloud, the dataset is very different in terms of the distribution of the points along the axis ?